# Single instance of a class per HTTP request

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httpwebrequest, singleton

To debug my ASP.NET application I created a class called `MessageHandling.cs`. At this point it's a singleton pattern but I want it to be an instance per request.

My `mssqlDb` class fills the `MessagesHandling` class with messages like: 'Db connected', 'Data inserted' and stuff like that. After all the Events of the apsx page are processed the `MessageHandling` class is read by `createFile.apsx.cs` in the event `Page_LoadComplete()`. All the errors and messages will be showm to the user.

At this point the system works for debugging. The problem at this point is that the MessageHandling isn't emptied after the request has been send and the errors are also shown on the second browser without doing anything. I also want to be able to use this system for showing messages to the end users like: "Blog created".

The basic of my problem is the following:
`Class A` creates `Class B`
`Class C` reads `Class B`

The singleton doesn't work because it's not per user / session / request. So I need an other method.

Comment: Where do you first instantiate your singleton?

Comment: The mssqlDb is the first one to use it. So that's the place where it is initiated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Store it in the [`HttpContext.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx), that way it will be for each request.

[HttpContext.Items - a Per-Request Cache Store](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx)

Comment: Nice, I didn't even know this existed... learning something new every day

Comment: is there another way to do this? have a library that is accessed from both .net framework and .net core and HttpContext can not be shared between the two.

Comment: IMemoryCache https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 5):

`HttpContext.Current` is the `HttpContext` object for the current request. It has an `Items` property which is an `IDictionary` from `object` to `object`. You can put anything you like in there, and it will be tied to the current request.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check in the constructor of your singleton to see if that object exists in the session? If not, create it and then return it?

```
private Singleton()
{
    // do whatever
}

public Singleton GetMySingleton()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Items["MyCustomSingleton"] == null)
        HttpContext.Current.Items["MyCustomSingleton"] = new Singleton();
    //

    return (Singleton)HttpContext.Current.Items["MyCustomSingleton"];
}
```

Comment: ya, my bad. didn't see that part